# Error: No pubspec.yaml file found. in MAC

Tags: terminal, flutter

I am new in flutter. After installation on MAC , while running "flutter run" in terminal , I got error as :

```
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.
Do not run this command from the root of your git clone of Flutter.
```

Anyone please can help me to fix this error ??

Comment: Did you run from the root of your Flutter project? This directory should contain a `pubspec.yaml`. Did you check the file exists there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you did not create the project: Open Android Studio or your IDE and [create a new flutter project](https://flutter.io/get-started/codelab/#step-1-create-the-starting-flutter-app). Also make sure that you set up your environment correctly [like in the docs](https://flutter.io/setup-macos/).

This command you are trying to run `flutter run` is meant to compile the project in the current directory and then run it on an emulator or device.